# Excel Vlookup Formula

Tags: excel, vlookup

Hello Excel Vlookup Experts,

I am trying to get a VLOOKUP formula to do the following.  Using the columns E, F, and G as references, I am trying to populate data to column C. Column A and B must match column E and F to populate column C.  Notice that column B has hours with the Date.  I just want the data from column C to populate regardless of the hour, if it matches(Column A and B must match column E and F).

End result as shown:

[image]

Comment: Make a helper column for A+B (less hour) and another for E+F. Then VLOOKUP on those.

Comment: Voting to close as `Needs more focus` to be a well-posed question.  You have not stated what you have tried.  What `VLookup` or `Index/Match` formula have you tried that is not working?  There are numerous questions out there about this topic.

Comment: I need the hours to be intact as it is required

Comment: Consider merging using power query. It is built to be able to join on multiple keys. Otherwise, as @L.ScottJohnson should work fine.

Comment: Vlookup one column to another is not the difficult task.  I am not understanding or if possible to lookup 2 columns to match another 2 columns, one being with a date time with hours.

Comment: I'd insert column `G` as `=E2 & F2` to combine Well_ID and Date, then use `VLOOKUP($A2 & INT($B2),$G$2:$H$3,2,FALSE)` to return the value from column `H` (Data).

Comment: Thanks Darren.  Will try that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try following formulas -

`SUMPRODUCT`- if combination of Well_Id and Date is unique:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A2=$E$2:$E$21)*(INT(B2)=$F$2:$F$21)*$G$2:$G$21)
```

`INDEX/MATCH`array formula - if not unique, it returns first match:

```
{=INDEX($G$2:$G$21,MATCH(1,(A2=$E$2:$E$21)*(INT(B2)=$F$2:$F$21),0))}
```

Array formula after editing is confirmed by pressing `ctrl` + `shift` + `enter`

[image]

Comment: Thanks.  I was able to do it by this formula:          =INDEX(VALUE(DATA!$C$2:DATA!$C$293580),MATCH(A2&ROUNDDOWN(B2,0),VALUE(DATA!$A$2:DATA!$A$293580)&VALUE(DATA!$B$2:$B$293580),0))

Answer (score 0):

This one should do it, make sure to apply it with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>

```
=INDEX($G$2:$G$21,MATCH(A1&ROUND(B1,0),$E$2:$E$21&$F$2:$FE$21,0))
```

Comment: =INDEX($G$2:$G$21,MATCH(A2&ROUND(B2,0),$E$2:$E$21&$F$2:$F$21,0))    getting results as for date 2-04-202 as 52 (2/5/2020)

Comment: How do you remove the round?      =INDEX($G$2:$G$21,MATCH(A2&B2,0),$E$2:$E$21&$F$2:$F$21,0))